# Promise resolved too fast

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am using Promises and in the meanwhile i have a loading animation.
the problme is that my promise is resolved fast and the loader is quickly disappear.

So i want to launch a promise and if the promise is resolved before 3 sec wait the remaining time.

**Example**

```
export const operation = () => {

  const a = new Date();

  const myPromise = doAction().then(() => {

   const b = new Date();

   if((b - a) < 3000)
      operationIsDone();
   else
     setTimeout(() => {operationIsDone();}, b - a)

  });  
}
```

Is there any npm or a better way doing it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's how I do it too in my fakes. Simple, short, effective.

Comment: `b-a` will most likely result in a very small number, so basically the callback of `setTimeout()` will be executed right away. What exactly is ist, this part is supposed to do?

Comment: I would recommend to use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date`

Comment: This code makes no sense. `b - a` is `Date.now() - Date.now()` which is `0` in most cases (or occasionally `1`). Which time do you want to wait for?

Comment: sorry i forgot the most important call ill fix it in a few

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier to use a second promise that just runs the minimum waiting time. Then use `Promise.all` to wait for both to finish.
That way, your script will always wait at least the default delay but also longer if `yourOwnPromise` takes longer than that.

```js
const wait = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
const doAction = () => wait(500); // TODO replace this with your own function
const yourOwnPromise = doAction();

yourOwnPromise.then(() => {
    console.log('yourOwnPromise resolved now');
});

Promise.all([yourOwnPromise, wait(3000)]).then(() => {
    console.log('both resolved now');
});
```

See [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for details.